# Sign out of Windows Live Messenger remotely

Tags: remote, windows-live-messenger, logout

I just upgraded Windows Live Messenger at home. I'm logged into my machine at work so I have a Live session active there too. Now the fun part. This new version of messenger is signing me out after about 2 minutes, and saying "You were signed out from here because you signed in to a version of Messenger that doesn't let you sign in at more than on place"

Ok, so I went into the options on my home machine and selected "Sign me out at all other locations".

Is there another way I can force my office machine to logout remotely, as either this option does not work, or the machine in my office just keeps reconnecting.

Version 2009 14.0.8089.726

EDIT: Actually this problem went away after a few hours; I guess some kind of server side timeout kicked in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AH HA! I was having this problem also, and I believe I have found a work around. In the short period of time you can stay logged on go into the options menu and turn OFF as in UNCHECK the "Sign me out of all other places when I sign into Messenger" option and make sure that the "Show me all the other places I'm signed in at when I sign in" option is CHECKED. Hit apply and just let it log you out again like it always does. Then, the next time you try to log in you will get a popup with a list of all the places you are signed in, with the option to sign out of each of these place. Use this to sign out on your other computer(s). This seems to acctually sign you out at the other places correctly so that you may remain logged in at the current computer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered making a batch script to kill messenger on the remote computer?

```
TASKKILL /S system /U username /P password /F /IM msnmsgr.exe /T
```

Where **system** specifies the remote machine's name or IP to connect to. You will need to allow it in your firewall. If you don't want to bother with firewall rules or there is a router at the office you can't access, consider leaving [Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com/index.aspx) running so you can quickly login and disable it yourself remotely. Teamviewer does not require additional router configurations from experience.

Comment: Interesting I'll try that, infortunately it involves going to work and it's a holiday.

Comment: If you're referring to the batch script, you run that locally, not at your workplace. If you want to set up teamviewer you'll need to go there unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could just install a free software like logmein.com and remote to it, logout and than login anywhere else you wanted to. I don't know if there is a setting that will auto logout anywhere else once you login from another place.

Comment: Windows remote desktop does the same thing without third party software.

Answer (score 0):

Go the options on live messenger and under sign in check the box that says; "Sign me out of all other places when I sign in to Messenger"
You also could install the messenger extension; http://www.msgpluslive.net/ 
it allows multiple logins